# Making liquor with normal milk instead of UHT milk

Tags: liqueur

I would like to make a liqueur, using alcohol with 40% and other ingredients. Two of those are (according to the recipe) UHT-milk and UHT-cream. Unfortunately I could not find any source for them where I live at the moment. Thus I was thinking of replacing the UHT milk with normal milk.
Would that work? And how fast would I have to drink the liqueur now, assumed the alcohol content (~20 % in the final product) does not keep the milk fresh?

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment but I have no reputation so I apologise if not much of help.

Anyway if you're trying to accomplish something like a cream-based liqueur, sure you can use normal milk.

I've prepared a Baileys-like liqueur with normal milk and uht crem and results were amazing!

The lifetime of the product was unaffected by the use of a fresh product (storage lifetime in fridge was something like 3 months due to alcohol and sugar added to the mix)

Answer (score 2):

In the US, while UHT milk can be found, it is not the standard, widespread  product generally used. Therefore, cream liqueur recipes simply call for cream or cream & milk, with no specification for UHT.

What we consider 'normal' grocery store milk is homogenized and pasteurized or ultra-pasteurized. Ultra-pasteurized products are pretty much the same as UHT products, the main difference being the packaging.

Either product, whether pasteurized or ultra-pasteurized, should be an acceptable substitute. One possible consideration depending on your recipe - while I haven't personally experienced it, I have read that ultra-pasteurized cream doesn't whip as well as pasteurized cream. But since your recipe calls for UHT cream, it should be fine.

So, your recipe should turn out fine using 'normal' milk and cream, if your 'normal' is as described above.

Regarding shelf life, most recipes I've seen call for the finished product to be refrigerated. (Although some may not.) And most state the expected length of time it should keep for.

I would think that if you use ultra-pasteurized products, the length of time would be as your recipe states. It could possibly be less with pasteurized products, but I would also think that could vary depending on the preparation method.